# How to show 20 fake items when loading the recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to show some list of items in a recyclerview, following the next article [GIT REPO](https://github.com/giolaoit/LoadMoreRecyclerView). I need to load 20 fake items before the recyclerview loads the next real items, as a loading. But I don´t know how to insert this cells and later.

Someone could give me a hand?

[image]

Comment: do same way as after the items load, but create 20 items manually, and use them

Comment: Before you pass your ArrayList or List to your adapter make sure you add some dummy value.

Answer (score 0):

"Fake" items are just "items" to `RecyclerView` – there's no difference between them. Hence to show them you'd have to use the same thing you use to show "ordinary" items in `RecyclerView`s: a `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

The component responsible for placeholder views like the one you've shown above is actually the activity/fragment containing the `RecyclerView`. Here's a rough illustration of how it might work:

1. Make sure your adapter could handle (at least) 2 view types: one for your real view, one for the placeholder.
2. Whenever you're loading your data, add [null objects](https://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/09/12/what-is-a-null-object-and-when-are-they-useful/) to your adapter's `List`.
3. Configure your adapter to inflate a placeholder view whenever it's being asked to render a null object.
4. When your data is loaded, replace those null objects with an actual object coming from your data store.